# Android: Looping through a string array - help needed on logic for intent method

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-intent, logic

I'm a java novice and I've using the code below to display a list of clickable TextViews that call a specific class when they are clicked.

It is a list of football team names.

Eg.

Arsenal 
Manchester United
Chelsea

Clicking on TextView Arsenal (TextView id = ars) will call ars.class
Clicking on TextView Chelsea (TextView id = che)will call che.class

I have over 20 football team names.

I have an array of textview ids, which I loop through and assign them a clickable action. This works fine.

I have an string array of teamnames, the code loops through the string array and assigns each teamname to a Class object, which is used in the Intent() method.

When I run this code, the list is produced but when I click on a team name it always opens Wol.java, the last position in the string array.

I need some help with the logic, so that when I click on Arsenal it opens ars.class

Here is the code.

```
public final int[] teams = { R.id.ars, R.id.ast, R.id.bir, R.id.bla,
        R.id.blp, R.id.bol, R.id.che, R.id.eve, R.id.ful, R.id.hul,
        R.id.lee, R.id.liv, R.id.mid, R.id.mnc, R.id.mnu, R.id.nor,
        R.id.nwu, R.id.por, R.id.qpr, R.id.sto, R.id.sun, R.id.swa,
        R.id.tot, R.id.wes, R.id.wig, R.id.wol };

     //String array of teamnames, named to correspond their class name.
public final String[] teamnames = { "ars", "ast", "bir", "bla", "blp",
        "bol", "che", "eve", "ful", "hul", "lee", "liv", "mid", "mnc",
        "mnu", "nor", "nwu", "por", "qpr", "sto", "sun", "swa", "tot",
        "wes", "wig", "wol" };

TextView tv;
Class classname;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.m_transfers);

    setTeamNames(); //Method sets up team names to a Class name.

    for (int i = 0; i < teams.length; i++) {
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(teams[i]);
        tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent open = new Intent(Transfers.this, classname);
                startActivity(open);
            }
        });
    }
    ;
}

public void setTeamNames() {
    for (String s : teamnames) {
        String name = "ttj.android.ft.teams." + s;

        try {
            classname = Class.forName(name);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    ;
}
```

Comment: Are you seriously saying you've created 20 different Activities, one for each team? Why not just have one `Activity` (called `TeamActivity`  for example) and pass the team name as a string `Extra` in the `Intent` you use for `startActivity(...)`?

Comment: Very new to android development, still getting my head around the Manifest. Yes, I have created 20 seperate activities in the manifest. Could I make a TeamActivity in the manifest?

Comment: @tiptopjat You could make one TeamActivity in the manifest the same way you made the 20 different activities and then, as MisterSquonk said, just add a string or int to the Intent to differentiate.

Comment: Thanks guys, I will give this a go. When you say Intent, are you referring to Intent-filter in the xml file or the Intent method in java? Apologies for the noobie questions!

Comment: @tiptopjat: See my answer. No you don't need an `<intent-filter>` in the manifest for `TeamActivity` because you create an explicit `Intent` specifying `TeamActivity.class` - no intent filter needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`classname` is being overwritten every time you iterate in the foreach loop inside `setTeamNames()`. Thus, only the last classname remains at the end.

If `teams` and `teamnames` have the same number of entries (which they should), you can use the following code and get rid of `setTeamNames()` completely.

```
final String prefix = "ttj.android.ft.teams.";
for (int i = 0; i < teams.length; i++) {
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(teams[i]);
    tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View v) {
       try {
          Class class = Class.forName(prefix + teamnames[i]);               
          Intent open = new Intent(Transfers.this, class);
          startActivity(open);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
}
;
```

Comment: Duh! Thanks Tushar! :-) Only problem I have with this is line 7. Class class = Class.forName(prefix + teamnames[i]);   Eclipse says I can not refer to a non-final variable 'i' inside an inner class defined in a different method.

Comment: Right, I forgot. You'll either have to set your teamnames and prefix as final or declare them inside the OnClickListener() class.

Comment: Thanks for replying back. 'teamnames' is already Public Final. I've tried declaring teamnames inside the OnClickListener() class. Still no joy.

Comment: Did you make String prefix final as well?

Comment: Yes, inside the method Eclipse asked for it to be final. So I moved it outside the method as 'String prefix = "ttj.android.ft.teams.";'  The problem still persists. If I made the int in the for loop final, the i++ increment throws an error.

Comment: On the first line inside your for-loop, add `final int j = i;` and then replace `teamnames[i]` with `teamnames[j]`. That may be the problem.

Comment: Absolutely fantastic! Thank you! It works. I've spent 6 hours trying to work this out, should have registered to this site sooner. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the activities you are trying to start have similar (or the same) layout and functionality but display different data specific to each team, try the following.

Change your `onClick(View v)` method as follows...

```
tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent open = new Intent(Transfers.this, TeamActivity.class);
        open.putExtra("team", ((TextView)v).getText());
        startActivity(open);
    }
});
```

Then create a 'generic' `Activity`...

```
public class TeamActivity extends Activity {

    String teamName = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set the layout here

        // Get the Intent and team name with the following...
        teamName = getIntent().getStringExtra("team");

        // Do something with teamName

    }
}
```

Just register the `TeamActivity` in your manifest and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this solution. I imagine the app will be more efficient using this approach? I've invested so much time in my approach I don't have the energy to start from scratch. Lol.